# JavaScript object identity

Tags: javascript, object, identity

I'm currently working on my first more complex JavaScript project. It's going fine so far, but now I'm kind of stuck.

I've got one central array of objects. These objects are generated by an constructor function, in case that's of importance.

Let me show you the problematic code before I continue:

```
this.VariableChanged = function (variable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ruleSets.length; i++) {
        var triggers = ruleSets[i].GetTriggers();
        for (var j = 0; j < triggers.length; j++) {
            projectManager.VariableManager.GetVariable("MyVariableName").value = "SomeOtherValue";
            if (triggers[i] == variable) {
                ruleSets[i].Trigger();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the first line of code within the most inner for-loop to check whether both objects `triggers[i]` and `variable` are the same. Just for debugging purposes. And in fact they seem to be, both objects hold `SomeOtherValue` in the value property after this line of code.

However `triggers[i] == variable` returns false. How is this possible?

I could use the ID which belongs to every Variable object, so this isn't a showstopper. But I'd like to know whats happening here.

Comment: I need a bit more context in your particular case, but: "And in fact they seem to be, both objects hold SomeOtherValue in the value property after this line of code." sounds weird. The fact that two objects have the same properties does not mean they are the same object. ```a = { value: 1 }; b = { value: 1 }; a == b``` will be ```false```. Equality is not the same as equivalence.

Comment: Before that line of code,both objects held another value. After that line, both objects got "SomeOtherValue" as their new value.

Comment: What is the varialbe value? are you checking trigger[i] with projectManager.VariableManager.GetVariable("MyVariableName").value?

Comment: You refer to them as _objects_. I don't think you cannot check equality of objects using `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here it is:

In a part of my code I didn't posted above, I pushed an array into another. Not every item individually, but the whole array.
For some reason, after pushing an array into another one, the objects within both arrays aren't identical anymore.

If I push them one by one, it works just fine.
Here's a simple example:

```
var array1 = [{}];
var array2 = [];

array2.push(array1);

//Alerts false
alert(array2[0] == array1[0]);

array2 = [];
array2.push(array1[0]);

//Alerts true
alert(array2[0] == array1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `.value` property of both objects is the same, but the containing objects are not. Imagine this:

```
person = { name: 'Bob' };
a = { guy: person };
b = { guy: person };

// The containing objects are not the same
a === b; // false

// But their property 'guy' is!
a.guy === b.guy; // true

// so changing it, changes it in both objects
person.name = 'John';
a.guy; // { name: 'John' };
b.guy; // { name: 'John' };
```

The fact that two objects contain inside of them the same object does NOT mean that the containing objects are the same.

Comment: That's a good point. Is there a way (for example with Chrome Debugger) to check if both references are pointing to the same object?

Comment: Sure, just check ```triggers[i].value === variable.value``` or whichever the two inside objects are :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you compare two objects, it will always return false. Example:

```
b = {};
a = {};
a == b
// Output : false
```

In order to compare two objects based on their values, you can run a 'for in' loop in one object and compare the value of that property in the other object. Hope you get it.